# Can't Install Package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I Was Trying to Install this package but this keeps getting error. I also Tried Changing The Target Framework to 4.7 and 4.7.2

> Installing 'Anviz.SDK 2.0.4'.
>
> Successfully installed 'Anviz.SDK 2.0.4'.
>
> Adding 'Anviz.SDK 2.0.4' to Anviz.
>
> Uninstalling 'Anviz.SDK 2.0.4'.
>
> Successfully uninstalled 'Anviz.SDK 2.0.4'.
>
> Install failed. Rolling back...
>
> Could not install package 'Anviz.SDK 2.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: You have tagged this issue with Visual Studio 2013, I assume that's the version you are using? 

The problem is that the package in question supports netstandard2.0 and Visual Studio 2013 as a toolset does not recognize the netstandard2.0 framework.

You'd need a newer Visual Studio version to take a dependency on this package.

Comment: @imps Okay, thanks for answering my concern.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from a comment to answer to get full resolution of the issue.

The problem is that the package in question supports netstandard2.0 and Visual Studio 2013 as a toolset does not recognize the netstandard2.0 framework. You'd need a newer Visual Studio version to take a dependency on this package.